# Shiny: How to hide and show elements based on keypress / key. input

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build an app in shiny that hide / shows "pages" when a specific key is pressed to simulate an implicit association test. Participants at the beginning get instructed and then (from IAT1 on) have to press either "e" or "i" when a specific word appears and then the next word should be presented. This means that the first word should disappear and the new word appear when "e" or "i" is pressed. As I did not get very far right now after IAT 1 (word 1) not the second word is presented but the welcome page again to test the key input.

Instead of `e.keyCode` I also tried `e.which` but the key input seems not to change anything or to let elements appear / disappear and I don't know what I am doing wrong or where the problem might be.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(
    id = "welcome",
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        h3("Welcome"),
        p("Welcome to the test."),
        br(),
        actionButton("continue1", label = "weiter")
      )
    )
  ),
  
  hidden( 
    div(
      id = "instruction",
      mainPanel(
        fluidRow(
          h3("Instruction"),
          p("Please ...")),
        br(),
        actionButton("continue2", label = "weiter"))
        )
  ),
  
  hidden( 
    div(
      id = "IAT1",
      mainPanel(
        fluidRow(
          h3("IAT"),
          p("IAT word 1")),
        br(),
        tags$script('$(document).on("keypress", function(e) {
                    shiny.onInputChange("keyid1", e.keyCode);
                    });'))
        ))

      )
#####server#
useShinyjs()
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$continue1, {
    show("instruction")
    hide("welcome")
  })
  observeEvent(input$continue2, {
    show("IAT1")
    hide("instruction")
  })
  observeEvent(input$keyid1,{
    if(e.keyCode == 69) {
    hide("IAT1")  
    show("welcome")
    }
    else {}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I added the keys (`e`,`i`, `SHIFT+e`, `SHIFT+i`)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    div(
        id = "welcome",
        mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                h3("Welcome"),
                p("Welcome to the test."),
                br(),
                actionButton("continue1", label = "weiter")
            )
        )
    ),
    
    hidden( 
        div(
            id = "instruction",
            mainPanel(
                fluidRow(
                    h3("Instruction"),
                    p("Please ...")),
                br(),
                actionButton("continue2", label = "weiter"))
        )
    ),
    
    hidden( 
        div(
            id = "IAT1",
            mainPanel(
                fluidRow(
                    h3("IAT"),
                    p("IAT word 1")),
                br(),
                tags$script('$(document).on("keypress", function(e) {
                            Shiny.onInputChange("keyid1", e.keyCode);
                            });'))
        ))
    
            )

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    observeEvent(input$continue1, {
        show("instruction")
        hide("welcome")
    })
    observeEvent(input$continue2, {
        show("IAT1")
        hide("instruction")
    })
    observeEvent(input$keyid1,{
        print(input$keyid1)
        if(input$keyid1 %in% c(101,105,69,73)) {
            hide("IAT1")  
            show("welcome")
        }
        else {}
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```